# How to do "term centric + phrase" search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tf-idf

Elasticsearch "multi-match + cross_fields" is doing [term centric](https://enterprise-knowledge.com/how-to-optimize-search-relevance-by-tweaking-your-search-approach/) search. Which is a nice feature, since I really don't need the per-field-IDF.

I want to do a Phrase search, and want to do it the "term-centric" way, but it seemed that both "cross_fields" and "combined_fields" don't support phrase.

So is there any other way? Thanks.

I tried "multi-match + phrase", but it is doing per-field-IDF, don't match my need.

Detailed Sample:

1. create index

```
    PUT /testindex
    {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        },
        "mappings": {
          "properties": {
            "fn":    { "type": "text" },  
            "ln":  { "type": "text"  }
          }
        }
    }
```

2. add 10 same documents

```
    POST /testindex/_doc/{from 1 to 10}
    {
        "fn": "hello world",
        "ln": "bye"
    }
```

3. add another document, but put "hello world" in "ln":

```
    POST /testindex/_doc/100
    {
        "fn": "bye",
        "ln": "hello world"
    }
```

4. I want to do a phrase search on "hello world".

```
    POST /testindex/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "hello world",
                        "fields": ["fn", "ln"],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but as "multi-match+phrase" is field-centric, so IDF of "hello world" is very high on "ln" field, resulting the last document scored much higher. The above queries returns the following, which is not what I want:

```
    {
        "took": 5,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 11,
                "relation": "eq"
            },
            "max_score": 3.1015396,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_index": "testindex",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "100",
                    "_score": 3.1015396,
                    "_source": {
                        "fn": "bye",
                        "ln": "hello world"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "testindex",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_score": 0.26195967,
                    "_source": {
                        "fn": "hello world",
                        "ln": "bye"
                    }
                },
    ...}
```

Comment: Could you please add sample query and data, that will help us to understand your question in better way.

Comment: @SagarPatel thanks for help. I updated my question, please have a look.